# .Where Lambda expression loading entire table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

I have set up an entity framework project with a code-first approach:
[Link to code-first approach](http://www.codeproject.com/articles/547016/code-first-approach-using-entity-framework-4-1-inv)

I have added a method to access the repositories by inserting a function:

The interface for the repository:

```
IQueryable<T> GetMany(Func<T, bool> where);
```

The EntityRepositoryBase method:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetMany(Func<T, bool> where)
{
     return dbset.Where(where).AsQueryable();
}
```

Example of how I access it:

```
genericRepositoryName.GetStuffInHere(x => x.Name== "Billy");
```

However, when this is executed it is loading the entire table and filtering the data down. This, as you can imagine, takes a long time. I have a ByID approach that uses .Find() which correctly executes a query and gets the record in milliseconds flat. I am completely stumped as to why this happens - or what I am doing wrong. Is there a better approach to grabbing all records with a field, let's say, that contain a string of "Hello". It takes ~5-10 seconds with the current process to get records back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

at a guess...

with linq, to turn it into a sql query it must be given an expression tree which it can then translate into sql.  I think your Func screws that up

try just `dbset.Where(x -> x.Name=="Billy);`

or as Kirk points out in the comments, change to an expression tree:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
```

Comment: Right, or just change `Func<T, bool>` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

Comment: You can also get rid of the `AsQueryable` once you do that.  The fact that you needed it to begin without should have been a hint that you were using the IEnumerable overload of `Where` rather than the IQueryable version.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, `dbset` isn't `IQueryable<T>` or a `DbSet`. It's probably some fashion of `IEnumerable<T>`, which is causing the entire table to be fetched and filtered in C# instead of SQL.

I'd make sure you're not changing the dbset into an enumerable anywhere by calling `ToList()` or putting it through a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I will run through my code when I get back to work tomorrow!

Comment: Not sure - was not I. I went through and checked.. found a `code`ToList()`code` but it still did not work. Going to work on the other answer today, see if it helps! Unfortunately, I cannot vote him up :(.